# URL refused by machine

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, windows-services, cloud

'

I am trying to connect to one of the cloud hosted application from my windows service and problem is it was not able to connect to the url.

I tried to browse the url in browser also it was not able to browse it and when I tried with the IP address the system browser can able to browse the service and I am wondering how it is not connecting now and previously it was connected.

Initially I tried with url like **http://zzzz.cloudapp.net/XXXXX.svc** , the browser refused it and then I changed into IP address like **`http://192.168.4.14/XXXXX.svc`** and now it worked.

Any suggestion how to fix this, because that the cloud hosted app IP address will change if I restarted the service.

Comment: "the browser refused it" what's the error/result the browser showed?

Comment: asked to Check the url is correct or not

Comment: Is that possible that dns address has been changed?

Comment: http://192.168.4.14/XXXXX.svc is a local ip to you. You are just looking at you local machine. More than likely you have setup your WCF service wrongly. Check your web.config settings.